# Varying foler size in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs, ext4, thunar

I know that Linux doesn't show the total size of the contents in a folder as the folder size as Windows systems do.
The following screenshot shows what I mean:
[image: LinuxFolderSize]
Unlike shown in the image, the total size of the content in the folder, for example 'fonts', isn't just 64KiB, but it amounts to about 160MiB(I don't exactly know the reason behind this, but it is answered at a Stackexchange site, so I am not asking about it).
The thing I am interested about is the different sizes shown for the different folders like the 'fonts' folder is 64KiB but 'Gadgets' is 8KiB while 'Serie' is 0 bytes.
What is the reason behind these differences?

More info:
The file manager used is Thunar, and the file system of the partition is NTFS with 16KiB allocation size. This also happens in an ext4 formatted partition as well, but very less.

Comment: are you sure it happens on ext4 ? folders should always be at least one block (so usually 4kb)

Comment: Related, at least the answer is pretty much describing what is going on even if on a different filesystem: https://superuser.com/questions/585844/why-directories-size-are-different-in-ls-l-output-on-xfs-file-system/585846#585846

Comment: @HoD That is correct. In ext4, they are at least 4KiB, but the size varies.